# Subtracting a Minute in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a variable in Perl that I initialized as `$invoice_date = '1/6/14'` (June 1st 2014).  How can I determine the datatype that Perl considers this variable to be?

I'd like to subtract a minute from the invoice date to get May 31 2014 11:59PM.  How can I do this with or without declaring $invoice_date to be a certain datatype?

Update: Thanks for the comments and answers.  Since it is a string, I am going to try to concatenate the time portion.  I have a another variable $period_end_date which is set to May 31, 2014.  I'm going to try to concatenate the 11:59PM to it.

The string is subsequently sent in a SQL statement.  If I can figure out what SQL expects for the string, it should be possible to insert the time portion.

Comment: Have a look at the [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module. Googling around for the answer if always a good step before posting here, there are many results for this question.

Comment: to Perl, this is a string

Comment: As for what 'SQL expects for the string', it depends on the database. Sybase will accept many different formats. Oracle expects whatever the NLS_DATE or TIMESTAMP parameters are set to...and/or you may need to just call your database's string to date conversion function.

Comment: It is Sybase.  It didn't like my string when I added the time.  I'm checking the Sybase documentation now.  The code actually calls a stored procedure to do the SQL.  Hopefully, I can just change the value of the parameter.

Comment: I finally got it.  I couldn't figure out how to send a string to the stored proc so that it would show up as a dateadd Sybase command in the SQL and not a string.  So I ended up converting the period end date's value of '05/31/14' piece by piece to 'May 31 2014 11:59PM' with a if elsif statement to get the month abbreviation, adding 2000 to the year and including the time in the constructed string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some date manipulation module as `'1/6/14'` is plain string, and two digit years were abandoned prior to [Y2K](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem) event.

```
use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $t =  Time::Piece->strptime("1/6/2014", "%d/%m/%Y");
$t -= ONE_MINUTE;
print $t;
```

output

```
Sat May 31 23:59:00 2014
```